# How to update a particular object from a remote which has not been synced yet?

Tags: pouchdb

I have a pouchdb database which is synced with a remote couchdb. On occasion I find that certain objects have not been synced yet. How can I force a sync of the particular object immediately on those occasions?

Is get() from remote and put() into local the way to do this? Is it worthwhile providing a shortcut api for this?